# Akka tapping into message stream, IllegalArgumentException from Props

Tags: unit-testing, akka

I have an actor representing a shared resource. A worker Actor accepts it as a constructor argument in following manner:

```
class Worker(G: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    G ! Graph.Look(start)
    ...
}
```

I am attempting to devise test code for the Worker/Resource interaction, but falling short with:

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val worker =  system.actorOf( Props(classOf[Worker], probe.ref))
probe.expectMsg(Look(0))
```

The intended idea is to examine every request to G and forward it to the real actor, observe the consequences for few iterations. However the above code results in this runtime error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class Worker for arguments [class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef]
```

If this is not the correct way to test this cycle of interaction, what is the alternative

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3"
    , "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.3"
...
```

Comment: Is Worker an inner class? If so it needs the ``this`` pointer to the outer class in its constructor (yes, really).

Comment: That's not the case, but good to keep in mind for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question is **wrong**. My actual worker has **two** arguments:

```
class Worker(G: ActorRef, startState: Int) extends Actor {...
```

What is happening is that the Props with ClassTag call is turning a compile time error into a runtime error:

```
val worker =  system.actorOf( Props(classOf[Worker], probe.ref))
```

should be

```
val worker =  system.actorOf( Props(classOf[Worker], probe.ref, 0))
```

The runtime error produces, as in original question, is a little confusing because it sounds like  there is a type-mismatch and `akka.actor.RepointableActorRef` at some point extends `ActorRef`. While in fact it's the whole constructor signature that was not matching.

This is somewhat frustrating because this error "upgrade" is something I was aware of when avoiding the now deprecated syntax of:

```
val worker =  system.actorOf( Props(new Worker(probe.ref, 0)) )
```

I would be embarrassed except this was a really easy mistake to make, I feel I won't be the only one.
Leaving this here for posterity.

Comment: Haha definitely don't feel embarrassed! This is an insanely easy mistake to make. As such, A recommended practice can be found [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices). Using this method of companion objects plus a convenience method, you can guarantee that you'll find these guys at compile time instead of run time.